# Is there a bing API?

Tags: search, bing-api

Microsoft has just launched a new search engine, Bing, "Bing Is Not Google".

Does this service have an API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this Bing API, Version 2.0 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251056.aspx

Answer (score 2):

according to this 
http://dev.live.com/blogs/livesearch/archive/2009/05/28/494.aspx you use the Live API

you get a link to this : it looks like changes to the Live API - "Silk Road" aka live search 2.0 http://search.live.com/developers

[MSDN LowBand Link to the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251056.aspx)